# Make Style "Spacing" dependent on the following Style (in MS Word)

Tags: microsoft-word, styles, line-spacing

Is there a way to make a Style1 dependent on the following Style2?

I have a document with text (Style1, with 12pt spacing after) and some quotes (Style2).
If there's text in Style1 and then after it text in Style1, Style3, Style4, ... (NOT Style2), it should have the 12pt spacing.

But if there's text in Style1 and then after it text in Style2, it should ignore the 12pt-spacing from Style1 (make no spacing).

I tried to make it easier to understand with a screenshot. If the red part (spacing) would be not existing, it would be what I try to do.

[image: screenshot]

---

Thank you all very much for your help and ideas!

Kind regards Photelegy

Answer (score 0):

### Sorry, no can do. Here's a workaround.

Word makes the spacing for each paragraph semi-independent of other paragraphs. Each paragraph has space-before and space-after formatting. This should be set in paragraph styles.

If the following paragraph has a space before setting that is less than or equal to the space after setting of the current paragraph. You can indicate that you want to suppress the spacing for paragraphs of the same style.

[image: dialog box]

### Workaround

What you can do as a workaround, is create a new style, based on the one that has the space after setting. In that style you can:

1. Have no space after, or less space after.
2. Set the style for following paragraph to be the Style2.
3. Set a keyboard shortcut for your new style. [Assigning Keyboard Shortcuts](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word-mso_win10-msoversion_other/assigning-keyboard-shortcuts-in-microsoft-word/a346f277-e0eb-4d17-b53b-233584c611bb?tm=1595883735330)

Comment: Thank you very much for your fast answer!
Whould there be a way to apply Style2 to a text seperated by Style1 with a Shift+Enter?
With Shift+Enter it doesn't make the spacing but then the Style will be applied to the whole part and not just the quote. And if a change the Style2 "Styletype" to "Charakter" I don't know how to add the "Outside Border".

Could something like this be a solution?
If not I try your workaround. 

Comment: I have 2 spontanious ideas:
1. Is there a way to use Shift+Enter (between Style1 and Style2).
2. Is there a way to use "Style type" as "Character" or so (so it can be used after a Shift+Enter)?
Thank you very much!

Comment: No, as to both. Shift+Enter continues the current paragraph, it does not create a new paragraph. Character styles do not deal with paragraph or line spacing. Paragraph borders can only be controlled in paragraph styles. Here is my chapter on styles. https://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/styles.htm  Note that Word comes with a built-in Quote style, which is a paragraph style.

Comment: Ok, thank you for your great explanation! I'll use your workaround.

Comment: To have a better idea of what is happening in a document it is important to view the non-printing formatting marks, especially the paragraph marks. http://wordfaqs.ssbarnhill.com/NonprintChars.htm